# How can I enable text input to Siri on the iPhone Xs simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

A quick Google search of this question tells me all I have to do is go to

> Settings > Accessibility > Siri

and toggle the Type to Siri option, which is no problem on my physical phone, but there is no Siri section under Accessibility in the iPhone simulator. Does anybody know a different way that this can be done in the simulator?

Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing in the Accessibility tab:

[image: Accessibility settings in iOS Simulator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is indeed unavailable for the Simulator.

A workaround for this is typing something into the Spotlight Search and tapping on the Ask Siri button afterwards. This is avaiable **from iOS 13 and onwards**.

[image: Ask Siri option in Spotlight Search]

---

**For iOS 12 and below**, your only option is saying something to Siri and tapping on Tap to Edit, then typing in the thing you want:

[image: Tap to Edit option in Siri]

[image: Edited input for Siri]

Comment: lame... Thanks for the confirmation though.